# Different Spark versions used on using the source code and getting a pre-built version

Tags: apache-spark

I have downloaded Spark source code(branch 2.4) and built the jars using the built instruction for `Hadoop 2.7.4`. I have also downloaded a pre-built version of Spark 2.4.4(Pre-built for Hadoop 2.7).

When I start `spark-shell` I see two different versions of Spark as shown in the picture below:

[image]

[image]

In the first picture, version is 3.0.0 for the jars built after downloading source code of branch 2.4. The second picture is from the pre-built version available from apache spark website. Not only that, the plans are using `RelationV2` in first case and `Relation` logical node in second case.

Can anyone explain why is there such a difference?

Comment: Your question(s) is not clear. First off, please specify the two spark-shell commands you are using (you are not having two splash screens on a single command)
Secondly provide the links to the jars you downloaded for build. Downloading 2.4 would give you 2.4, not 3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure you got mixed up, as 3.0.0 is the default choice for dowloading source or prebuilt version. Maybe I am mistaked, but, as of my comment, carefully check what version you have built.

[image]

Comment: You were right. I had been cloning wrong branch source code all this while.